# Multi maven project module spring boot + VueJS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, maven, vue.js, deployment

How can I deploy on AWS a spring boot project with multi module maven for backend and one module maven for frontend (this with VueJS)?

Answer (score 0):

A Spring boot app can be deployed to the AWS cloud in many ways. For example, you can deploy a Spring boot app to the Elastic Beanstalk. It does not really matter how to build your Spring app - as long as you build a FAT JAR that contains the dependencies. For the front end, also it does not matter. I personally like using Thymeleaf.